# Why do we have bacteria in our alimentary canal?

Tags: digestion

Our alimentary canal contains lots of bacteria. Most of these are found in the small intestine and large intestine.

Can you a give a few reasons why is it a good thing to have bacteria in our digestive system.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If yes - homework questions are warmly welcomed, barred OP shows prior efforts to answer them. Have a look at our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) in the [help center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help). If not, we generally still expect users to give a question at least a shot on their own. For example, What are *your thoughts* on the subject? Which reasons can *you think of*?